# Would the game think I am being account sitted if I log on a mate's smartphone?

Tags: die2nite

Would the game think I am having my account sitted if I log on via my mate's smartphone for the next few days?

I am losing internet and would like to finish this town, but I am afraid the system would think I am letting my mate log in for me.

He plays the game too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Motion Twin support page](http://support.motion-twin.com/help?lang=en;site=56;cat=17#118):

> **Can I share the computer with a friend or a relation to play one or more of Motion Twin's websites?**
>
> Yes. Several people can log in on the same computer to one or several of Motion Twin websites.
>
> It's not necessary to notify us if you share a computer with more Motion Twin players.